# Tool chain 'ndk-gcc' (GNU GCC): XCode arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is a wrapper around Clang

Tags: android, animation, toolchain, fbx, assimp

> Tool chain 'ndk-gcc' (GNU GCC): XCode arm-linux-androideabi-gcc is a wrapper around Clang. Treating it as Clang and not GCC.

Stuck with this project compilation issue. unable to compile.

Comment: How didi you try to compile, cmake?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/sgeb/gradle-android-arm-clang-plugin

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you need to set the parameter

```
toolchain = 'clang'
```

in the build.gradle file. It seems to be set to gcc.